# Bloomberg Excel API, how to extract one number out of BDS

Tags: bloomberg, excel

The BDS function provided by the Bloomberg Excel plugin produces multiple cells. For example, =BDS("VOD LN Equity", "TICK_SIZE_TABLE") fills three columns and 19 rows of data. The third column contains tick sizes from 0.0001 to 10. How can I extract just the largest value, i.e. 10? I would like the result to take up only one cell. Many thanks.

Comment: Probably best to use the helpdesk for this kind of question

Comment: I already tried with a related question. Their approach was to ignore it. When I suggested they might like to get back to me, they said "we will let you know if there is an answer". In fairness, I have also had better experiences with them, but asking what to do after their API returns a result probably will not work.

Comment: This seems like an Excel formula question? Use _MAX_ function to find the largest value in 3rd column, then [_MATCH_](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) to get its row number, then [_INDEX_](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd#bmarray_form) to get the value in this row  and column 2. However instead of BDS, you should use BQL. Then you can perform all this logic within BQL call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function builder makes it possible to figure out an answer. If someone knows where in the documentation I could have found this, it would be helpful to know for the next time.

```
=BDS("VOD LN Equity", "TICK_TABLE_SIZE", "Aggregate", "Y", "SortDesc", "3", "StartCol", "3", "EndRow", "1")
```

Comment: Switch from BDS to BQL.

Comment: @Dmitri Vulis That seems even harder to get to work. If you (or anyone) posts an answer explaining how, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: HELP DAPI - Constructing Formulas > if you do not find it there, it almost certainly does not exist. It is part of the standard BDS syntax explanation - {LPHP DAPI:0:1 2754307 <GO>} for a direct link (within BBG). Not sure how stable this link is in the long run to be honest. I do not think BQL is showing this field.